# @Editable does not work right with Multiline Text field; always shows as empty in EE

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

Using Sitecore 9.3, we have a component that renders multiple fields from the datasource as editable fields, like so:

`@Editable(model => model.Datasource.Quote)`

Every field works right except for the Multiline Text field. The Multiline Text always displays as empty (`[No text in field`]), even though there is text in the field and the text shows in preview

I changed the field type in Sitecore to Rich Text, and that made it work right; Single Line Text also works right. Just Multiline Text. But I really want to be able to use Multiline Text because the authors need to enter multiple rows of text but cannot have HTML tags end up in there

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002418:

Fix the value of `Rendering.HtmlEncodedFieldTypes` in the config:

```
<setting name="Rendering.HtmlEncodedFieldTypes" value="text|single-line text|multi-line text" />
```